# How to add additional paths to baseurl using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, for-loop

I have a base URL

```
url= 'www.baseUrl.com'
```

I have an array of my paths `Paths = [path1,path2,path3]`

how do i create something like perhaps i need to do a loop?

```
www.baseUrl.com/path1
www.baseUrl.com/path2
www.baseUrl.com/path3
```

Comment: @Sammy: sorry, questions are meant to be useful *long term, for other visitors*, and so answers and questions are seen as a whole. Changing your question after having received answers is not really acceptable, your additional array of ids would make it a new question. I've rolled back that change.

Comment: @Sammy: sorry you feel that way; if you have a new question, you are free to post one. However, lets keep things constructive here, no need to get defensive. This is a moderated and curated question and answer site, which is why you can find so many high-quality solutions here. What you are experiencing is the moderating and curating in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map one array to another:

```
const paths = ['path1','path2','path3'];
const url= 'www.baseUrl.com';


const fullPaths = paths.map(path => `${url}/${path}`);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

Go through your Paths-list and manipulate the items like this:

```
url= 'www.baseUrl.com/'
newPath=url + path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/forEach)

```
let url = 'www.baseUrl.com';
let paths = [ 'path1','path2','path3'];
let urlsWithPath = [];

paths.forEach(path => {
  let singleUrlWithpath = url + '/' + path;
  urlsWithPath.push(singleUrlWithpath);
});
```

And then, urlsWithPath array will containt those 3 urls

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want something like this:

```
let url = 'www.baseUrl.com';

const paths = [
    'path1',
    'path2',
    'path3',
];

function getFullUrlByPath(path) {
    return url + '/' + paths[path++];
}

getFullUrlByPath(1);
// Will return www.baseUrl.com/path1
```